# Grails: Response headers full and no response sent

Tags: grails, spring-security, http-headers

```
| Error 2012-10-29 14:51:19,847 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] ERROR http11.Http11Processor  - Error processing request
Message: An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2012-10-29 14:51:19,850 [http-bio-8443-exec-3] ERROR http11.Http11Processor  - Error finishing response
Message: An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.
   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

This happens very randomly in my local development environment (*grails run-app -https*). No matter what the browser is.

I'm running Grails 2.1.0 on Mac OSX with the following plugins:

```
aws-sdk             1.3.12           --  AWS SDK Grails Plugin
cookie-session      0.1.2            --  Cookie Session Plugin
hibernate           2.1.0            --  Hibernate for Grails
jquery              1.7.1            --  JQuery for Grails
jquery-ui           1.8.15           --  jQuery UI resources
mail                1.0              --  Provides Mail support to a running Grails application
newrelic            0.1              --  Newrelic Plugin
qrcode              0.3              --  QR Code plugin
quartz              1.0-RC2          --  Quartz plugin for Grails
resources           1.1.6            --  Resources
spring-security-core1.2.7.3          --  Spring Security Core Plugin
tomcat              2.1.0            --  Apache Tomcat plugin for Grails
webxml              1.4.1            --  WebXmlConfig
```

Any ideas what could cause this?

**EDIT:**
Noticed that this seems to happen after logging in (Spring security login form) when the browser is forwarded to j_spring_security_check. With Chrome & Firefox it's possible to stop this happening for a while by reseting the browser. IE doesn't behave similarly, instead just keeps giving this error (the error is shown only in grails console).

There's something that fills the headers. Possibly the *cookie-session* plugin?

Comment: I get this when I upload a file and try to redirect the user.